# Spark - Group and Count By Similar Strings (Scala or Pyspark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I have about 15 million strings in a DataFrame that I need to analyze. What I would like to do is group these in string similarity. The eventual goal is to count similar strings to get some statistics. Here's an example of the type of strings:

```
Apple
Banana
Tilamook Butter
Gala Apple
Pinto Beans
Salt
Granny Smith Apple
Generic Butter
Butter
Black Beans
Beans
```

My Grouping would look something like this:

```
Apple
Gala Apple
Granny Smith Apple
Banana
Tilamook Butter
Generic Butter
Butter
Pinto Beans
Black Beans
Beans
Salt
```

And the count would be:

```
Apple - 3
Banana - 1
Butter - 3
Beans - 3
Salt- 1
```

I did some research into clustering but couldn't find a good example for this type of problem.

Edit: Also, we should take into consideration that these strings can be spelled improperly, for example,

```
Butter
Bttr
Beans
Bean
Salad
Salat
```

Comment: You would likely need further classification information, rather than just a string description. For example, "Butter Beans" would need to be classified as a type of Bean, rather than a type of Butter - but you have no easy way of doing that. (BTW, should the count field read `Beans - 3`, not `Pinto Beans - 3`?)

Comment: I've done something similar to this using Python and Fuzzy matching where basically I pull each record, check against a list, if nothing matches the list, I would add it to the list with a key and then check the next one and continue from there. I did this in SQL Server though and it was very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using spark and Scala. save the data in a file and create RDD using sparkContext like below. Note: `sc` represents sparkContext

```
val stringsRDD=sc.textFile("C:\\spark\\programs\\strings.txt")
```

stringsRDD is the RDD of strings, Now you can iterate over each string and split it into words

```
val wordsRDD=stringsRDD.flatMap(str=>str.split(" "))
```

The wordsRDD contains

```
res3: Array[String] = Array(Apple, Banana, Tilamook, Butter, Gala, Apple, Pinto, Beans, Salt, Granny, Smith, Apple, Generic, Butter, Butter, Black, Beans, Beans)
```

Create a simple map where key is word and value is 1

```
val wordMapRDD=wordsRDD.map(word=>(word->1))
```

The wordMapRDD contains

```
res4: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Apple,1), (Banana,1), (Tilamook,1), (Butter,1), (Gala,1), (Apple,1), (Pinto,1), (Beans,1), (Salt,1), (Granny,1), (Smith,1), (Apple,1), (Generic,1), (Butter,1), (Butter,1), (Black,1), (Beans,1), (Beans,1))
```

Now you can easily apply `reduceByKey` function

```
val wordCountRDD=wordMapRDD.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

The wordCountRDD contains

```
res5: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Tilamook,1), (Butter,3), (Salt,1), (Pinto,1), (Apple,3), (Gala,1), (Black,1), (Generic,1), (Granny,1), (Beans,3), (Smith,1), (Banana,1))
```

Note: If you want to see that what RDD contains then you have to use `collect` method like below

```
wordsRDD.collect
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this!

Comment: Extension though, what if we have a sample that's say {Butter Beans}. It's going to count this as both butter and beans correct? Also, what if Butter is spelled improperly and is say btter.

Comment: If you want such type of result then you have to apply NLP.